# How do I change my whm/cpanel to use a FQDN and SSL?

Tags: hosting, cpanel, web-hosting, whm

I have purchased a server through GoDaddy and when I access WHM or the CPanel, it uses the IP address of the server rather than the host name.  How to I change this to use the host name and put SSL on that host name?

Answer (score 0):

You could access WHM both on IP and hostname. Please check if your server actually has a valid hostname. If not, then you can't use WHM via hostname, so you'll have to configure a domain on that server and create a hostname for your WHM server.

Answer (score 0):

Upon provision I was given a hostname of the form:

s192.168.2.###.secureserver.net  This will not resolve in a browser. Nor will a ping -a to an IP address. It is a temporary hostname. It will work for creating resellers and putting up websites but you will not be able to secure it with an SSL cert as far as I know. You need a hostname that is also a domain that resolves to your server's primary IP address to allow login to WHM.

And the server has a requirement for hostnames as being an FQDN.  The requirements for an FQDN are:

```
 - Do not select a hostname that begins with www or a number, or a hostname that ends with a hyphen (-).
 - You must use a fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) that contains two periods (for example, hostname.example.com).
 - Do not choose a hostname that a cPanel account on your server will use.
 - Do not choose a potential proxy subdomain as a hostname (for example, cpanel.example.com or whm.example.com).

 - Do not select a socially-unacceptable hostname. The hostname will appear in mail headers.
 - Only use lowercase, Latin-script letters in hostnames.
```

On the part that requires that you install an SSL for connecting to a URL and port number I cannot address yet but I purchased a cheam domain name from Godaddy, it was then auto parked.

1. Went into the DNS records for the domain and pointed the A record to the primary IP address of the server. 
   Record: A     @    192.168.2.####    TTL: 18000
2. You will want to delete all the other records listed there as an FQDN cannot have any subdomain or potential proxy. So no CNAMEs allowed.
3. Leave Godaddy's name servers NS as they are.
4. Give the domain settings time to propagate. (i.e. 15min - 24hours)
5. Connect back to your WHM via ip (https://192.168.2.###:2087)
6. Navigate to Basic Setup or enter Basic Setup into the search and click on the link.
7. Change the NS servers at the bottom of the page to GoDaddy's name servers.
8. Save Settings change.
9. Enter the new hostname in the Set Up Networking section of WHM's Initial Setup Assistant interface.
10. Save your settings.
11. Navigate to your new domain name preceded by "https://" and followed by ":2087" (i.e https://mynewhostname.com:2087 ).

I believe this will get you at least that far for your process.